# is there a way to have a contant plotting graph to plot user's input points on, without having to create a new graph for each user input? python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Is there a way to create one continuous graph that interactively plot user's input on, without having to create a whole new plot each time?

This is my attempt. It does work but it keeps creating a whole another "instance" every time a name is entered.

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

selected_names = []
while True:
    user_input = input('Enter name: ')
    selected_names.append(user_input)
    for i, j, name in zip(xs, ys, names):
        if name in selected_names:
            plt.scatter(i, j)
    plt.show()
```